# how to make existing pdf editable? Android app

Tags: android, pdf, pdf-extraction

I'm making an app in android.I'm able to write text and create a new PDFs and also can read existing PDFs.
But i'm not getting solution to edit the existing PDFs.
Editing the PDFs in my app is the target which i have to  achieve.

I tried to convert it in String but its in encoded  form.Have searched a lot But i don't want to use any paid libraries or jar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally PDFs are not designed to be editable and do not contain structure information. You can use some tools like Acrobat to try to put structure back in but it is a huge task.

Comment: But does android support Acrobat,i mean if you can just elaborate how to use acrobat and edit in android.I have tried doing parsing but they are generating in bitmap for i.e image which is not useful for me.

Comment: Most PDF viewers on Android are wrappers around bitmaps). Adobe reader is on Android but AFAIR the full Acrobat is not